# Extremely slow retrieval images (stored in bytes[]) from SQL Server in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am storing images in SQL Server in `bytes[]` and then retrieving it using VIEWDATA as following (there are nine images (`bytes[]`) in database which I am retrieving):

Action controller:

```
public ActionResult show_pics2()
{
    using (cygnussolutionEntities6 db = new cygnussolutionEntities6())
    {
        // db.CommandTimeout = int.MaxValue; //For test
        var querylist = (from f in db.Images
                         select f.ImageContent);

        // get list in ViewBag
        ViewBag.DataLIst = querylist;

        // get list in View Data
        ViewData["images"] = querylist.ToList();

        return View();
    }
}
```

In view, I am parsing images and displaying it with foreach loop and `viewDATA`, but it's taking so long to load to browser. Does anyone knows why this is taking so long?

Comment: Why are you storing same object `querrylist ` in ViewBag and ViewData?

Comment: thats nothing i just commented viewBag

Comment: How many images in `db.Images` and how big are they?

Comment: 9 images and they are 475 KB in size

Answer (score 0):

It would be worth putting some timers through your code to see where the slowness is occurring - i.e. is it the query to the database that is slow, is materialising the result into a list slow, or is the slowness occurring within the view when processing the images.

Also worth considering - are you eager-loading any properties from the Images table as that will affect performance depending on the number of extra navigation properties being loaded.

Are you able to post the code within your view and your entities class?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are going to `ToList()` something and also going to use it elsewhere, then make both uses use the results of the `ToList()` (unless you really need to maintain the queryable interface). Then you need only get that list once.
2. Don't obtain several blobs and use them on a page, obtain several IDs and use them to call other resources through `<img src="theImage/@id">` or similar, then have that resource served by a view that only retrieves the sole image. Then each such resource loads a single image and can do so in parallel to each other.
3. Unless the images are all small, use streams that build on ADO access to the blob and stream out a chunk of 4096 bytes at a time, rather than EF. While it means leaving a lot of what EF give you (and a lot of what MVC gives you since you'll have to do it in a result rather than a view) it allows for memory-efficient streaming that can begin with the first loaded chunk.